# Best class naming conventions with multiple implementations

Tags: python, oop, naming-conventions, factory-pattern

I am dealing with a project in which I have to implement a rather complex data structure P into several ways (all of them in python). Hoping it could be of some help, here it is how I structured a portion of my project:

```
+ P/
|----+ A/
|    |----p.py
|
|----+ B/
|    |----p.py
|
|----factory.py
|----abstractP.py
```

in `p.py` I have the different implementations of P as classes. They are all named the same, as `P` (they all conform to an interface since they inherit from a class `abstractP` which extends `ABCMeta`).

I am planning on using the factory pattern to properly instantiate an object of class `P` by specifying a parameter. At the moment, in `factory.py` I am avoiding name clashes by using python import tricks:

```
from P.A.p import P as P_A
from P.B.p import P as P_B
```

I'm doing so thinking that I could use `p.py` files indipendently in next project so I am not naming the classes `P_A` and `P_B` from the start.

Is this a bad practice? What would the best naming convention for the implementations in this context?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably name them after some particular aspect of their implementation.

Take for example a couple of typical implementations of a list type container:

- abstract class List (defines the basic interfaces/behaviour of a "list")
- class LinkedList (a linked node implementation of that behaviour)
- class ArrayList (an array based implementation of that behaviour)

You name the specific implementations after how they are implemented.

Comment: `A` and `B` are the implementation name parts, made name themselves. In short your point is to use `P_A` and `P_B` from the beginning, am I right?

Comment: Basically, yes, but I don't think that "A" and "B" are good names for anything. Nor is "P" for that matter, but I'm assuming you're just using them as placeholders?